# Update UILabel but previous value not disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In objective c, I am trying to update the text value for a UILabel which is in a table cell. However, after updating, previous text value of that UILabel does not disappear. The code is as following:

```
- (void)buttonDidClicked:(PYBCartButton *)button
{
    [self configureTotalPrice:20.0];
}

- (void)configureTotalPrice: (double) totalPrice
{
    self.totalPriceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".2f", totalPrice];
    //[self.contentView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And it shows like that:

[image]

The old value is behind the new value. I don't know the problem.

Comment: Well, the problem isn't in the code you posted.. Are these methods inside your table view cell class? Or, do you have something like an outlet set up on the totalPriceLabel in your view controller?

Comment: My money's on the label being added as a subview to the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` without first removing any potential existing instance of the label.

Comment: please give some detail about your problem and tableview cell for row code

Comment: @ChrisSlowik Yes, I have a delegate in the table cell so should I change the value in the table cell?

Answer (score 0):

The most probably reason this could be happening is two UILabels. Check that the label that holds the value of 600.00 is in fact hooked up to self.totalPriceLabel.